# Probability, Expected Value, Standard Deviation

Tags: probability, expected-value, standard-deviation

[image]

I did not understand part c. How should I calculate it? Can someone please show it?

Comment: What is $\mathbb P\{|X-\mathbb E[X]|\leq 1.5 \}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did not understand part c.

after some calculations you get that

$$E(X)=7$$

$$\sigma(X)\approx 2.65$$

They request you to calculate

$$P(7-1.5\cdot2.65\leq X\leq 7-1.5\cdot2.65)=$$

$$=P(3<X<11)=1-2[P(X=2)+P(X=3)]=1-2\left[\frac{1}{36}+\frac{2}{36}\right]=\frac{30}{36}$$

Comment: Sorry but isn't X supposed to be between 5.5 and 8.5 if I follow  this  value- P{|X−E[X]|≤1.5}

Comment: @Novice sorry, misread the question. Now it is correct